# #1054 - Unknown column 'ats2' in 'where clause' in sub query on same table mysql version 5.6.4

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

```
SELECT *, (
    CASE WHEN ats1.time_slot_id = 48
    THEN 1
    ELSE ats1.time_slot_id
    END
  ) AS temp_time_slot_id,
  (
    SELECT id
    FROM allocated_time_slot
    WHERE from_time >= '2018-10-11 06:25:40'
    AND patient_id IS NULL
    AND doctor_id = '1167'
    AND time_slot_id = temp_time_slot_id
  ) AS ats2
FROM allocated_time_slot AS ats1
WHERE ats1.doctor_id = '1167'
AND ats1.from_time >= '2018-10-11 06:25:40'
AND ats1.patient_id IS NULL
AND ats2 IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: You cannot use aliased expression/column in the where clause

Comment: But you can use it in a HAVING clause. However, for s pathway to a better solution, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thanks both you :)